# ОШИБКА microdata: невозможно определить принадлежность данных полей

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, сниппет, яндекс-вебмастер

Для `seo сниппетов` на сайте размещаю микроразметку добавляя в строки

```
<title>заголовок сайта</title>
...
<div id="wrapper">
...
```

следующее содержимое

```
<title itemprop="headline">заголовок сайта</title>
...
<div id="wrapper" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
...
```

на что в [вебмастере яндекса](https://webmaster.yandex.ru/site/) получаю такую ошибку:

> microdata ОШИБКА: невозможно определить принадлежность данных полей.
>   Возможны две причины: эти поля некорректно размещены, либо указан
>   лишний атрибут itemprop itemType = headline = заголовок сайта
>   wpheader
>   itemType = http://schema.org/WPHeader

как заполнить поля корректно?

Comment: Надо анализировать исходный код всей страницы. Пожалуйста сообщите линк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В указанной вами разметке, элемент headline находиться вне зоны действия WPHeader. Возможное решение:

```html
<div id="wrapper" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
<title itemprop="headline">заголовок сайта</title>
</div>
```